# Sort a list in Jinja2 based on length

Tags: sorting, ansible, jinja2

I need to sort a list based on the length in "jinja2".
For example..

```
a = [ 'core', 'edge', 'darling', 'skynet' ]
```

is a list..
if i do a normal sort in "jinja2", it gave the result as

```
[ 'core', 'darling', 'edge', 'skynet' ]
```

but we want the result to show like below

```
['core', 'edge', 'skynet', 'darling']
```

Is there any way to get this in jinja2?

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

1. create a list of lengths of each element
2. zip the original list with the created in 1. - this will produce a list of tuples (lists)
3. sort the list created in 2. by the second tuple element
4. map the first tuple element

The code:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ a | zip(a|map('count')) | sort(attribute=1) | map(attribute=0) | list }}"
```

The result:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "core",
        "edge",
        "skynet",
        "darling"
    ]
}
```